# Python, Compare a list of numbers and continually loop until there's no duplicates

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to create a simple script that will help me for network planning.

I have a list of numbers--

```
subnets = [21, 21, 21, 19, 20, 23, 23]
```

For every duplicate, I'm looking to replace 2 duplicated numbers with a new number that's minus 1.  For example, replace (2) of the 21s with a 20.  Replace (2) 23s with a 22, and so on.

I've got--

```
x = sorted(subnets)
z = []

for a in x:
    if a not in z:
        z.append(a)
    else:
        z.remove(a)
        z.append(a-1)

print(z)
```

That kinda gets me what I want--

```
[19, 20, 20, 21, 22]
```

but there's (2) 20s in my final output, and that needs to be replaced with a 19, and then the (2) remaining 19s need to be replaced with an 18.

How do I continually loop my logic here?

My final output should be [18, 21, 22]

this below code gets me what I want, but it's nasty and I'm not going to know how many for loops to use as my subnets list changes, if I've got an additional 10 numbers in the subnets list, I don't want to have to change the script every time to keep creating these for loops

```
subnets = [21, 21, 21, 19, 20, 23, 23]

x = sorted(subnets)
z = []
y = []
v = []

for a in x:
    if a not in z:
        z.append(a)
    else:
        z.remove(a)
        z.append(a-1)

for a in z:
    if a not in y:
        y.append(a)
    else:
        y.remove(a)
        y.append(a-1)

for a in y:
    if a not in v:
        v.append(a)
    else:
        v.remove(a)
        v.append(a-1)

print(v)
```

Comment: your question seems to be in need of more details, what u mean about 2 duplicates??? are you gonna delete just elements with 2 time repeat?

Comment: anytime there's a number repeated, remove that number and replace it with a new number that's 1 less than the original repeated number.

Comment: Just run your loop in a while loop with a useful condition (like no duplicate found). And you should not modify a list you are iterating over.

Comment: Do you want to replace/remove _all_ duplicates, or just pairs? What do you want to do for three equal numbers?

Comment: DYZ posted a great solution-- any pair needs to be replaced with a new number that's 1 below the pair.  20 and 20 would be replaced by a single 19.  20, 20, 20 would need to equal 19, 20.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution may be suboptimal in terms of performance, but it seems easy to understand. You need a `Counter` object from the standard Python library that counts duplicate objects in a list.

```
subnets = [21, 21, 21, 19, 20, 23, 23]
from collections import Counter
```

The loop goes for as long as there are duplicates - that is, the length of the set of items is smaller than the length of the list of items (sets eliminate duplicates).

```
while len(subnets) > len(set(subnets)):     
    # [v-1] * (cnt // 2) - even # of duplicates 
    # [v] * (cnt % 2) - odd remaining non-duplicate
    # sum() rebuilds the list from the sublists
    subnets = sum([[v-1] * (cnt // 2) + [v] * (cnt % 2) 
                for v, cnt in Counter(subnets).items()], [])
# [18, 21, 22]
```

Comment: While undoubtedly clever, this is about a factor of 4 slower than [my simpler approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841344/1170207) (like you already estimated), at least for the short input given here.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa That's what I said in the very first sentence.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Also, for a longer list (700 numbers), my solution is 100 times faster than yours. Presumably because `remove` is a very slow operation.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. `remove` is O(n), and I am running the loop several times as well, so my solution probably scales like O(n^2). Your solution scales much better, so it's not suboptimal. There are probably faster algorithms, but this is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to your idea, we just run the replacement operation in a while loop, modifying a list in-place:

```
def replace_pairs_minus_one(inp):
    l = inp[:]
    while(True):
        for i, e in enumerate(l):
            if e in l[i+1:]:
                # pair found
                # here we modify the list, since we are breaking anyway
                l[i] = e - 1
                l.remove(e)
                break
        else:
            # break out of while if no pairs found
            break
    return sorted(l)

subnets = [21, 21, 21, 19, 20, 23, 23]
pairs_removed = replace_pairs_minus_one(subnets) # [18, 21, 22]
```